# Italic math font (via \mathit) not working for greek symbols with fontspec/lualatex/TeX Live 2015

Tags: math-mode, luatex, fontspec, mactex

(Updated to reflect newest findings.)

I recently switched to TeX Live 2015 and am struggling with a few problems in code that worked perfectly fine in TeX Live 2014. For instance: `\mathit` does not work with Greek symbols when using `fonstpec` and `lualatex`.

Consider this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
  $ A \Delta a \Gamma \mathit{\Gamma} $
\end{document}
```

By convention in my field of work, `\Gamma` is supposed to be italic (only this Gamma, not all Greek letters). Not using fontspec works fine. Once fontspec is loaded, the `\Gamma` just disappears without any warning. Including or not including `unicode-math` does not help.

Somehow this problem only occurs when TeX Live 2015 is used *and* all packages are updated to the latest versions (as of 2015-09-30). A clean install from MacTex 2015 is not affected. After updating the packages via TeX Live Utility, the slanted `\mathit{\Gamma}` is gone.

(TeX Live 2015, all packages updated, Mac OS X 10.10.5)

Comment: Just to verify: In your field, *all* uppercase Greek letters should be typeset slanted -- not just `\Gamma`, right? Please advise.

Comment: No, only _some_ Greek letters need to be slanted, like `\Gamma` in this meaning. Not even all `\Gamma` in the document need to be slanted.

Comment: The new commands in v0.8 onwards are `\symit` and so on for performing these transformations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of v0.8 of `unicode-math` `\mathit` functionality has changed. However, the new commands for single symbols work:

Use `symit`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
  $ A \Delta a \Gamma \symit{\Gamma} $
\end{document}
```

Legacy mode for documents relying on the old `mathit` behavior:

```
\usepackage[mathit=sym]{unicode-math}
```

See §4.4 of `unicode-math` documentation for more details.

Comment: Not broken, by design — `\mathit` now switches to "text italic font in maths mode" to be consistent with regular LaTeX.

Comment: No,  Latin Modern definitely has an ä,  but it does not show up with mathit.

Comment: @Will Robertson which font is used and how can I set it?

Comment: MaxNoe — Looks like a bug `:)` I must have forgotten to include `\mathit` to be auto-selected. You can use `\setmathfontface\mathit{...}` to choose that font explicitly.

Comment: If I do this: `\setmathfontface\mathit{Latin Modern Roman} ` I get upright `\mathit{}`.

Comment: (Max has continued the discussion on the fontspec issue tracker, but for anyone else looking, you need to explicitly load an italic font for `\setmathfontface\mathit{...}`.

Answer (score 3):

(Edited the answer after the OP clarified that only `\Gamma`, but no other Greek uppercase letters, should be rendered in slanted rather than upright shape.)

The following method should work with TeX installations that are a few months old (as of 2015/09/30) or older: You need to load the `unicode-math` package in order to make `\mathit{\Gamma}` work as expected. (To generate an upright `\Gamma`, just keep inputting `\Gamma`.)

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
  $ A \Delta a \Gamma \mathit{\Gamma} $
\end{document}
```

In contrast, if your system has version 0.8 (or later) of the `unicode-math` package -- see also Will Robertson's comment below -- you should write

```
\symit{Gamma}
```

in order to get the slanted glyph. Page 4 of the package's user guide explains the "new" syntax for invoking glyphs from various math alphabets.

Comment: And add `bold-style=ISO` for italics in bold math by default.

Comment: Not working for me. This makes `\Delta` (and all other Greek symbols) italic as well. Only `\Gamma` is supposed to be italic (not my decision…).

Comment: @FlorianKruse - Thanks for clarifying that only `\Gamma`, but no other uppercase Greek letters, should be rendered in slanted form. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mico: Sorry, still not working for me. Your minimal example produces a document with "AΔaΓ" ("susu", slanted/upright). Again, the last slanted Gamma is missing.

Comment: @FlorianKruse - Don't know what's going on. Am currently at a location from which I can't upload a screenshot. Will supply the screenshot tonight, if that's OK.

Comment: If you say it works for you, I believe you. Would still like to know why this is happening. I will try to find colleagues with TeX Live 2015 and check if it works for them.

Comment: I don't know if this changes the situation: I installed a new MacTex 2015 package on a machine with only TeX Live 2014 installed. Worked. Slanted Gamma appeared. Then I updated all TeX packages via `tlmgr`. Slanted Gamma disappears.

Comment: Removing all traces of all TeX installations and re-installing MacTex 2015 shows the same behaviour. MacTex 2015 out of the box: works; after updating all packages: slanted Gamma gone. Verified on two Macs with Mac OS 10.10 running.

Comment: works with the new `\symit{\Gamma}`, Γ also gone on arch linux

Comment: I thought I was more clear in the unicode-math documentation about this change, but perhaps not. As of v0.8, `\mathit` reverts to its original LaTeX definition of not affecting math symbol. As @MaxNoe says, the new command is `\symit`. But see Table 3 in the docs if you need backwards compatibility.

Comment: To be honest, I did not read the package documentation in detail after upgrading. My bad. Though I must say I do not keep track of all packages I am using and whether a major version change occured (i.e. I did not know which version I used in TeX Live 2014). The documentation is clear to me after reading. ;-)

Comment: @WillRobertson - Thanks for these comments. Real quick: Will you be updating the documentation in section 13 of the user guide of the unimath-symbols package in the near future? There, one can still find references to macros such as `\mitGamma`.

Comment: \mitGamma and so on remain as they are.